# Maxent.jar en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando llamar a Maxent en R para hacer un análisis

```
library(dismo) 
library(rJava)
file.exists(paste0(system.file(package=dismo), maxent.jar))
```

EL error solo me pone

```
FLASE
```

Comment: No sería en todo caso algo así: `file.exists(paste0(system.file(package="dismo"), "/", "maxent.jar"))` ? (Faltan comillas en las cadenas y falta separador de path)

Comment: Lo puse mal en la pregunta pero si, asi lo puse

Comment: Bueno, entonces el FALSE simplemente te está diciendo que no existe ese archivo.